# blockUI while loading and unblockUI after loading ASP.NET WebForm default page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-blockui

I currently have an ASP.NET WebForm "Default.aspx" which is called with POST data from another web page. It takes a while to load and i see a blank white page for a while.

I would like to blockUI when the loading happens and then call unblockUI when the loading is completed.

Which event should I hook into for blocking the UI?

I could use unblockUI in the window.load event.

Answer (score 0):

You can add jquery.blockUI.js for this purpose.Try adding it when ajax call happens and similarly unblock it.:

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
    $.blockUI(); 
/*      for css style
    $.blockUI({css: { border: 'none',
            padding: '5px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            '-webkit-border-radius': '5px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '5px',
            opacity: .5, color: '#fff' },
            message: "Loading..."}); */
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
     $.unblockUI();
    });
```

Comment: I do not have an AJAX call when loading the default page. So when do I call blockUI?